# How can I prevent deformation when rotating about the line-of-sight in OpenGL?

Tags: c, opengl

I've drawn an ellipse in the XZ plane, and set my perspective slightly up on the Y-axis and back on the Z, looking at the center of ellipse from a 45-degree angle, using gluPerspective() to set my viewing frustrum.

[image: ellipse]

Unrotated, the major axis of the ellipse spans the width of my viewport.  When I rotate 90-degrees about my line-of-sight, the major axis of the ellipse now spans the height of my viewport, thus deforming the ellipse (in this case, making it appear less eccentric).

[image: rotated ellipse]

What do I need to do to prevent this deformation (or at least account for it), so rotation about the line-of-sight preserves the perceived major axis of the ellipse (in this case, causing it to go beyond the viewport)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're using 1.0 as the aspect when you call gluPerspective().  You should use width/height.  For example, if your viewport is 640x480, you would use 1.33333 as the aspect argument.

Comment: Ah, I was dividing window width by height in my glutReshapeFunc() callback to get my aspect ratio, but I forgot to cast my width to a float first.  Bada-bing, Bada-boom, rounding error.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

According to the OpenGL Spec:

```
void gluPerspective( GLdouble fovy,
                     GLdouble aspect,
                     GLdouble zNear,
                   GLdouble zFar )
```

Aspect should be a function of your window width and height. Specifically width divided by height (but watch out for division by zero).

Perhaps you are using 1 as the aspect which is not accurate unless your window is a square.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the aspect parameter on your gluPerspective call need tweaking.  See [The Man Page](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/glu/perspective.html).  If your window were physically square, the aspect ratio would be 1 and your problem would go away.  However, your window is rectangular, so the viewing frustum needs to be non-square.

Set the aspect ratio to window_width / window_height, and your ellipse should look correct.  Note that you'll need to update this whenever the window resizes; if you're using GLUT set a [glutReshapeFunc](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/glutReshapeFunc.3.html) and recalculate the projection matrix in there.